# Rigged Object wont move in object mode

Tags: rigging

[image]So I have connected object to Lattice and Lattice to bone.003 and it is the bendy bone. So bone.001 moves the bone and the bone.003. And the bone.002 is the main bone what moves everything. Everything works fine in the Pose Mode as I planed but in the Object Mode Lattice and the object wont follow if I drag the Armature. Have look on the picture Any suggestions?

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: As you see everything is quiet simple to understand there is nothing difficult you can make such thing in seconds thing is everything works in pose mode but when you move armature in the object mode the object and the lattice wont move along

Comment: it makes things easier if we can test your setup, it looks like you're trying to move the object with the lattice, which is not possible, lattice will deform the object, not move it, what you can do though is parent both the object and the lattice to the armature, the lattice will follow and deform?

Comment: I Did parent option Bone and yes it follows but on the Pose mode when you rotate or move main bone the lattice and the object moves way to much and lose original position will say deforms .. idk .. anyway how you share the file?

Comment: Use  pasteall.org/blend and copy paste the link it will give

Comment: Opened link uploaded file and? That's it?

Comment: upload your file, copy the URL it will gives, and paste it here

Comment: what format should I save the file? Because when I save it it's 50.0 mb but the it accepts only 25 mb

Comment: maybe don't share your whole file, only keep the minimum, and use another platform if it's too heavy, like wetransfer, send to yourself and share the link it will give you

Comment: Okay will do new file

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/cf28d3204c4648ca92162d805e48a974

Comment: There it is Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Please if you sorted can you tell me how you did it and would be nice if you send me the file. On this one I didn't connect the lattice and and object to the armature because it cause the problem .. anyway I'm waiting for your respond

Comment: Ok I've answered, I hop it works

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the armature is no longer the parent of your lattice, so select the lattice, go in the *Object panel > Relations* and select *Armature*. Do it for the object called *GPencil* as well as you want it to follow.

[image]

Comment: Thank You You really helped me everything is fine now. I'm new with the Blender and I'm really grateful for your help. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome  ;)

Comment: It didn't work for my actual project. Once I parent the lattice or the object it change size and location. I cant share you the file because it weights 44mb

Comment: so maybe first unparent with Alt P > Clear and Keep Transformations, then do all the operations

Comment: I tried and It doesn't work, is there another way how can I share the file?

Comment: what if i just send it to your email is that posibble?